# "No module named catkin_pkg.package" error during Catkin make

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorial in
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

After installing ROS-indigo..I tried

```
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
$ catkin_make
```

But cmake command failed !!

```
chaluvad@nth:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/chaluvad/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.package
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/chaluvad/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
chaluvad@nth:~/catkin_ws$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250228/%22no-module-named-catkin_pkg.package%22-error-during-catkin-make/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2016-12-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-17**:
Please tell us how you installed ROS. Any tutorials you followed? `catkin_pkg` is a base package and should have been installed for you.

> Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:/usr/local/bin/python

are you using some custom version of Python? Built from source?

**Comment by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on 2016-12-17**:
Hi,
I just followed instructions from
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your version of python is in `/usr/local/bin/python` ; this means that at some point you've installed a custom version of python, and you're not using the system's version.

Your custom version of python probably isn't finding the system-installed python libraries. The general options here are to either remove the custom version of python, or install the required python packages where it can find them. Which option is better depends on why you installed a custom version, and whether you're still using it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1